# snort catches wrong package on ubuntu desktop 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, tcp, snort

Snort 2.9.7 + Ubuntu Desktop 16.04
Snort 2.9.7 + Ubuntu Server 16.04
All new installed&upgraded, and both run a simple script, the script just send a message('snort is hard to use') to a 192.168.223.2 every second

Here is my local.rules, just one line:

> alert tcp any any -> 192.168.223.2 1234 (msg:"To 192.168.223.2:1234"; sid:0;)

Here is command:

> sudo snort -c /etc/snort/rules/local.rules -A console -i ens33

Both systems could catch the package. BUT, use follow rule instead:

> alert tcp any any -> 192.168.223.2 1234 (msg:"To 192.168.223.2:1234"; sid:0; content:"snort";)

The desktop one can't catch any package but server one is ok.

With -vd option of snort, the 'snort is hard to use' be printed in both console, and only server os could catch the package, the desktop os catch nothing.

If without 'content' option of the rule, server os is still ok, the desktop os catched wrong packages, see the pics:

[1: server's, 2: desktop's wrong package be catched, 3: target package be passed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJED8.png)

I've tried vmware, vbox and real pc with Ubuntu Desktop version, all can't work.

Please help me to figure out the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Some times network card offloading prevent snort to work properly. Try to capture traffic in pcap format and check if layers checksum are OK.